# "Hyperledger Fabric chaincode invoke error: Config File 'core' Not Found"

Tags: chaincode

sudo peer chaincode invoke -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --tls $CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED --cafile $ORDERER_CA -C mychannel -n basic --peerAddresses localhost:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles $CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE_ORG1 --peerAddresses localhost:9051 --tlsRootCertFiles $CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE_ORG2 -c '{"function":"InitLedger","Args":[]}'
2024-03-13 08:33:32.921 UTC 0001 ERRO [main] InitCmd -> Fatal error when initializing core config : error when reading core config file: Config File "core" Not Found in "[/home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/test-network]"

i multiple time try but every time face same issue how can solve this error

2019-12-04 17:38:21.048 EST [chaincodeCmd] chaincodeInvokeOrQuery -> INFO 001 Chaincode invoke successful. result: status:200